# Geometry dash question about daily level

Tags: geometry-dash

When I go to the daily level, it sometimes says "Unknown" and when I go into it, it'll show the actual name of the song. Why?

Answer (score 1):

An unknown track happens when the song is deleted, or didn't get downloaded. It happens a lot in other parts of GD too. I.E: The song to Down Bass(extreme demon) got deleted so it shows as Unknown for some people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess that the request just took too long or failed or didn't get downloaded for some reason, this occasionally happens in other places too. It doesn't really matter besides for the annoyance.